# Create relations in postgres using Prisma

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I have simple tables like Post, User, Comment and Like. Every comment and post have Like[]. Need to describe Like model.In prisma docs there is [example](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/special-fields-and-types/working-with-composite-ids-and-constraints) with post + like relations, but when I add comment to it -> error.
Like model is :

```
model User {
  id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  email        String    @unique
  username     String
  password     String
  refreshToken String?
  createdAt    DateTime  @default(now())
  avatar       String?
  cover        String?
  bio          String?
  comments     Comment[]
  likes        Like[]
  posts        Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  content   String
  authorId  Int
  images    String[]
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  comments  Comment[]
  likes     Like[]
  author    User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
}

model Comment {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  content  String
  authorId Int
  postId   Int
  author   User   @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  post     Post   @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  likes    Like[]
}

model Like {
  userId    Int
  postId    Int
  post      Post?   @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  user      User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  commentId Int    
  comment   Comment? @relation(fields: [commentId], references: [id])

  @@id([userId, postId,commentId ], name: "likeId")
}
```

How can I do it right? Thanks for help.

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: I can't create new Like : need to provide comment to it. If I create 2 tables : one for post, second for comment - is this good approach?

Comment: you can use your approach - I see that both comment, post are optional relations on the Like model. Technically, this shouldn't throw an error when you're trying to create a new Like as long as you're passing in a postId